# Please make /review route available as a link somewhere

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

Pretty much a self explanatory request, really, but I discovered `/review` today and think it's great. I really think that it ought to feature somewhere on the home page or closely related pages.

Obvious areas for discussion:

- It should only be available to certain users above a certain amount of rep. I propose 3k and/or 6 months of reasonable activity level, but that's basically something I just invented right now and I'm not massively bothered what the constraints are, I just think there should be some so that only sufficiently experienced users can use it (whether experienced = time on site or rep, I don't know).
- I think it should have a nicer name. Well, I don't mind the /review in the url, but the link really ought to be called something that sounds less headmaster-ish and more "introductory". I'm rubbish at naming things, but let's just say it should be less "Help Vampire Eliminator XP Edition with Advanced Silver Bullet Technologies" and more "Community Watch" or "Guide new users".
- Whether it should feature on the home page, or close to it under another tab, and whether it should take up space at the top next to chat and meta or go somewhere else.

Disclaimer to this request: I haven't found this discussed before, I've no idea if you're hiding it because you're doing a Google and declaring it a "Beta" feature, or what is happening. I put out this request simply because I think it's a nice feature and you ought not to hide it away. I might also have missed an obvious link to it, but I'm only on a measly 6.9K rep, so I wouldn't know if it featured for the 10k+ users.

Reason I ask: nobody seems to know about it. It was new to me a few hours ago too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here's what Jeff said today:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/88954#88954)

> **At 200 rep, a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) entry appears in the top menu**; at 10k rep it switches to tools. We'll be linking to /review from tools as well, probably as a pseudo-tab.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Screenshot courtesy of Arjan</sup>

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the idea was to put the review page through its paces before unleashing it on the communities at large. Additionally, there may soon be [more things to review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/diff-is-hard-lets-go-shopping), so the page may not be considered finished yet.

As far as making it more accessible, Jeff [mentioned replacing the Unanswered button](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/436994#436994) with a link to the review route. I'm not sure whether or not this is still the plan, though, but I imagine if it is, it'll come sometime after the full functionality of the review route is complete.

Comment: Aaaaah I see. That would be really good I think. Can't wait to see what it ends up like.

Comment: I've done a user script so you can play with this [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2069/change-unanswered-tab-to-review)