# How about a Review link in the top bar for those with rep to use?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please make /review route available as a link somewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere)

Could we please get a 'Review' link in the top bar, so the review page will only be one click away?  Of course, this only needs to show for those with the rep to use.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Apparently it will replace the Unanswered button sometime.