# Link for review pages

Tags: support, review

Is there somewhere on SO website some kind of a "quick link" for review pages (first answers, low quality posts, ...) or is it accessible only directly by changing the url or through the link in description of Deputy badge?

Comment: Are you saying the link in the Deputy badge description doesn't work as a link?

Comment: @random: It works as a link, but it's also annoying to navigate every time through badges section in order to access review pages.

Comment: related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had talked about replacing "Unanswered" at the top of the page with "Review".

This will probably still happen at some point.