# Add "New answers from new users" to 10K tools links

Tags: feature-request, new-users, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

We have "new posts from new users" and "new answers to old questions". I'd love to see "new answers from new users". There are a lot of "thanks" and "me too" posts coming from new users, and this would help us catch them.

"New answers to old questions" partially gets this, and "new posts from new users" gets them as well, but with all the new questions in there, too. The link I'm suggesting would make it a lot easier to find "not an answer" posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/review` pages are supposed to catch most of these types of answers:

[First Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers)
[Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)

Comment: Where did that come from? Is there a link somewhere?

Comment: @sta [Badges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges)—see the deputy badge. SE has been thinking [about replacing the Unanswered tab with Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84693/), but for now, it's pretty well hidden.