# What is the newly added Review section?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the review queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)

What is the newly added [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) section and how to use it properly?

[image: Top menu on Stack Overflow]

Comment: What is unclear about the help in the right column, like: "These are the first answers a new user has ever submitted to Stack Overflow. New users may not always understand how our site works. Please review these posts and vote, comment, or flag them appropriately."

Comment: @Arjan, btw, I don't see that review link on mine.

Comment: I don't see it on SU either, @YOU. Guess 10k have their `tools` menu instead?

Comment: Nothing unclear. I am on stackoverflow from about a month. It seems I didn't discover all the services that right column provides .. rich column actualy ..

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere

Comment: @Arjan [It's linked inside tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/88954#88954)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The review section was already there but now there is a nice link to it [(thanks to this feature request)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere).
It looks like its only shown if there are no suggested edits (suggested edits is part of the review section).

You can use it to review several posts:

- first answers of new users
- low quality posts (according to an automated script)
- first questions of new users
- late answers to old questions
- suggested edits (not always available for anybody)

You can use this tool to improve the overall quality of the site. By using the powers given to you by the community. For example,

- you can edit/clarify a bad answer.
- you can add a comment to ask the original poster to clarify.
- you can close the real bad questions.
- you can flag for moderator support in case of spam or other undesired posts.

Comment: But I can not approve an answer as on topic and well written - I just can upvote it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I can click on "review answer" e.g., and all that is happening: stat counts goes up. I mean, I do nothing else like a choice from "need edit from experts" until "is good from all points". At least sth. like "I reviewed and say 'it is fine for me'" would help me to understand. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117236/review-what-is-it-why-is-it-not-in-the-faq?rq=1 helped me a bit. It is up to me to do sth. or not.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, yes, the review counter goes up if you click "review".