# How am I supposed to use the review link?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the newly added Review section?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88968/what-is-the-newly-added-review-section)
>   [How to review? Can we agree on a review 'policy'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-to-review-can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy)

I recently hit 2k and gained some new link called "review".  I'm just curious as to what I am looking at here...?  Is this a list of recently answered questions?  Why does this list exist?

Comment: @YOU - thanks, just didn't find it when I searched earlier. At first I did not notice the tabs at the top.  Now that I have its self explanatory.

Comment: (answering the question in the title only) you click it!  :)