# 'Review' What is it? Why is it not in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, support, review

Being new here I'm unsure what data the 'Review' link is providing me with. I can make a number of guesses - but I can't be certain about any of them. I took a look at the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) but couldn't find anything there so I'm wondering:

1. What is it?
2. Do you agree that this should probably be added to the FAQ, as I'm sure I'm not the first new user to wonder this?

Comment: At the very least, I'd think we'd have a "faq" post for it here on meta (marked with the moderator-only faq tag).  But I do not see one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The review page sidebar is pretty clear. From the "first answers" tab:

> These are the first answers a new user has ever submitted to Stack Overflow.
>
> - Upvote great posts!
> - Edit to improve formatting and give questions better titles.
> - Comment to provide guidance on how to ask and answer.
> - Vote to close off-topic questions, or flag them.

The other review tabs also have descriptions on their sidebars.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that or the tabs (curse my 4am brain). Makes things a lot clearer - thank-you.

Comment: Is it considered reviewing if I do one of the above from the "Review" tab or if I just edit/upvote/etc a question which happens to be for example a first time question?

Comment: @edem I don't know if it makes any difference. If there isn't a thread about it, start one with your question.