# How does the review system work?

Tags: discussion, review

I am new to this site and recently got access to reviewing posts on some of the beta sites.

I tried looking an FAQ documentation with no luck.  All I could come up with was this post,

['Review' What is it? Why is it not in the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117236/review-what-is-it-why-is-it-not-in-the-faq)

I understand the purpose of reviewing posts, but I am curious about a few things on this system works.

1. I see an 'is accepted' field on the right pane.  Does this indicate that the answer which is being reviewed is accepted?  If so, what relevance does it have while being reviewed? Does it  do nothing more than just give an indication to the reviewer that it is an accepted answer?
2. Should I verify whether the post just meets quality standards or should I also validate the answer to some extent?
3. What happens to the review when I click on 'Not Sure'?
4. When will a post be removed from review?  Will me marking the post as 'Not Sure' affect the review?
5. Why can't I just click a button saying 'Looks good' and move on without saying anything if the post appears to be fine?

**Edit :** Currently I am reviewing only first posts made by users.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it indicates that this answer is accepted.  It is mostly there, like so much else on the page, to just give you information that may or may not help you in making a decision.  For example, if an answer is accepted then it's likely it solved the OPs problem.  That is potentially valuable information for a reviewer.
2. You are free to do both, or either.  Several of the queues will make an effort to prioritize showing you questions/answers in tags you are active in so that you are more likely to be able to address the actual content of the post, but if you don't know enough about the material you are free to validate the non-content aspects of it.
3. You don't see the post again, and that's about it.
4. That will depend on which review queue you're in.  You appear to be discussing "first posts", although you haven't said so.  In that case, any *one* person reviewing an item will remove it from the queue.  Reviewing is defined in that queue as pressing "I'm done" after performing an action on the post.
5. Again, I assume you're referring to "first posts" because that button does exist in some queues, and doesn't make sense in the first place for others.  That particular question is a hotly debated topic as of late.  One argument given is that there is almost certainly *something* that *someone* can actually *do* for that post (given that commenting and voting are considered "actions" for the queue).  If you can't find anything that's perfectly all right, but that doesn't mean it should be removed from the queue to prevent someone else from doing anything.