# Where did this bounty come from?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Sorry if this is too localized, but my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/85989#85989) suddenly (i.e., I only just noticed) got a whopping +250.

It says it was awarded by Community. I've looked through a few discussions here on meta which I understand to mean it should indicate who is my real benefactor. I thought bounty could only be awarded on questions, not on specific answers, and judging from the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/84693/timeline) my answer was at no point higher voted than waiwai's.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within
>   7 days, **the highest voted answer
>   created after the bounty started with
>   at least 2 upvotes** will be awarded
>   half the bounty amount.

Bounty is dated **Apr 4 at 23:15**
[You answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/85989#85989) is dated **Apr 5 at 5:08**
[waiwai933 answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/84694#84694) is dated **Mar 25 at 1:24**

Comment: OK, thanks. Ironically, it didn't even occur to me to look in the FAQ :) It was the *after* the bounty bit which escaped me. That said, the fact that it was 'automatically' awarded means I don't get to know who it came from...

Comment: It was started by Jeff and half awarded by the Community user because Jeff has not directly awarded any of the answers.

Comment: Where do you look to see that? I've looked at history for question and answer, but not seeing it...

Comment: have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/84693/revisions)

Comment: OK, mea culpa, I looked at timeline instead of history...