# Please always show review link for 10k user too

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

Currently 10k users can only go to the `/review/suggested-edits` page if there is suggested-edits in queue:

[image: Current topbar menu: review only linked for pending edits]

Instead, please always show the `/review` link for 10k user like this:

[image: Proposed topbar menu: review always visible]

Jeff [wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/88954#88954) it will be linked from the tools menu some day, but that would be 2 or 3 extra clicks.